# org.bluez.Error.Failed: Raspberry Pi and obexpushd

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I am attempting to connect two Raspberry Pi's via Bluetooth. I have loaded all the libraries needed on both pis. Here is my methodology:

Boot the pi's

Run:

```
sudo obexpushd B-23 -o /bluetooth -n # On master pi
sudo obexpushd B-22 -o /bluetooth -n # on slave pi
Both print out the successful statement of listening on bluetooth.
```

Run:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
```

Make both pi's bluetooths discoverable.

On the master pi, connect to slave pi via the bluetoothctl command window. I then get the following error:

```
"Device B8:27:EB:8C:5D:## Connected: Yes"
"Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed"
"Device B8:27:EB:8C:5D:## Connected: No"
```

I have literally no idea what this error pertains to. Online forums have indicated this error occurs with audio devices. There is no audio device here.

I should note, I have been able to connect them. But they only stay connected for a very short time before they disconnect again. I see this message in the bluetoothctl command window. My goal is eventually, to have the slave and master connected and the slave sending files via ussp-push.

EDIT:

I followed along with these two guides:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=173478

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=963751#p963751

EDIT2:

Okay I was able to connect and have opened a new command window to run a sudo ussp-push command. There are still some problems:

The ussp-push command is only sending a 10 BYTE file, and has given no completetion message.

The bluetoothctl is now giving me the following error:

```
"Failed to connect: org.freedesktop.BDus.Error.NoReply"
```